# Unable to remove folder with GIT repo via command in VBScript

Tags: windows, git, command-line, vbscript, hp-quality-center

I am using Quality Center to execute tests in Windows 8.
The VBScript file creates a temporary (timestamped) workspace/folder to clone the git repository and execute the test.

When I try to remove the folder in the end of the test, it doesn't work and gives an error: **Invalid field type definition**.

This code works fine if I work with a non git repository and a static project. If I delete manually the **.git** folder, the script is able to remove the remaining of the folders/files.

```
'''workspace = "C:\tests\20170613224942"
Dim objFSO, objFolder
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.CreateFolder(workspace)

'git clone
'Test Execution

Dim objFSO, objFolder
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

objFSO.DeleteFolder(workspace)
```

I already tried (unsuccessfully) something like that:

```
objShell.Run "rmdir /S /Q " & workspace
```

I don't know if its problem with hidden folder so I tried this:

```
del /s /a *.git
```

But this only works for files and in this case only the folder is hidden. Not the sub-folders/sub-files.

Can someone help me to resolve this problem? How can I force the folder removal automatically via script?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try :

```
git rm -r gitDirectoryToRemove
```

and then your code to remove the parent if required

Comment: I tried and give me the error: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: Got it. Then you are trying to access the GIT / trying to command from an non-git directory. You should change directory to the git parent folder before entering the git command

Comment: Inside git parent folder, the command works but only the project/code is removed. The folder **.git** (problematic folder) its not deleted.

Comment: Which is the directory you actually trying to remove (say D:\workspace\temp\GitProject ) - here workspace OR temp OR GitProject ?

Comment: Try this - Go to git directory and then `rd /s /q` OR `del /s /q .git`
`rmdir /s /q .git` . Any of these should work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately only works if I execute them directly in command line. In VBScript do nothing. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Found a temporary solution. Maybe not an elegant one, but solves the problem.
I created a **.bat** file only for removing the folder passed by argument and I call it in VBS.

**Bat File:**

```
@echo off
@echo Try to removing %1
rmdir "%1" /s/q
```

**VBS Call:**

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run "C:\tests\rm_workspace.bat " & workspace
```

Removing indirectly, it works like a charm.
The reason: still don't know why.